# jQuery toggle doesn`t work

Tags: jquery, append, toggle, accordion, show

I have some problem with JQuery accordion.
I want to create "dynamic" accordion (to add new item by "addBtn"'s click),
a new item is created, but toggle does not apply (apply first item only)

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">

        <div id="aE">
                <div id="aT" class="aT_val"> 
                        <h3></h3>
                </div>
                <div id="aC" class="aC_val">
                        <p></p>
                </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
var conTit = 'title';
var conCont = 'content';

var count = 0;

$('.aC_val').hide();

$('.aT_val').toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).next('.aC_val').show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).next('.aC_val').hide();
    }
);

$('#addBtn').click(function() {
        count++;

        $('#accordion').append('<div id="aE' + count + '"><div id="aT' + count + '" class="aT_val"><h3>' + conTit + '</h3></div><div id="aC' + count + '" class="aC_val"><p>' + conCont + '</p></div></div>');
```

Where is bug, colleagues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamically generated elements, events should be delegated, you can use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.aT_val', function(){
     $(this).next().toggle();
})
```

Note that `toggle` event is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/).

Answer (score 0):

Does the accordion function not expect a `<h3>` tag after the

```
<div id="accordion"> tag
```

Example:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#"></a>General Variables</h3>
    <div>
    </div>
```